# What is the difference between "git show test.rb" and "git show HEAD:test.rb"?

Tags: git, git-show

Could you explain the difference between `git show test.rb` and `git show HEAD:test.rb`?

The command `git show HEAD:test.rb` returns:

```
test file contents
```

while `git show test.rb` returns:

```
commit a8e90b3dbf4eed03cdbb3cd3b99f98e9153c7219 
Author: Misha Moroshko <michael.moroshko@gmail.com> 
Date:   Thu Oct 27 17:03:04 2011
+1100

    asd

diff --git a/test.rb b/test.rb new file mode 100644 index
0000000..b48e119
--- /dev/null
+++ b/test.rb @@ -0,0 +1 @@
+test file contents
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git show` for commits will show the log message and textual diff. So that is what you get when you do `git show`, with the commit being assumed to be HEAD. And `git show file` shows the log message and textual diff for HEAD, filtered to `file`.

To show the content of the files at a particular commit, you do `git show commit:file`. So the `git show HEAD:file` shows the contents of the file in HEAD.

From `gitrevisions` man page:

> A suffix : followed by a path (e.g. HEAD:README); this names the blob
>   or tree at the given path in the tree-ish object named by the part
>   before the colon. :path (with an empty part before the colon, e.g.
>   :README) is a special case of the syntax described next: content
>   recorded in the index at the given path.

Also refer to the examples in the git show manual ( `git show --help`)

Comment: @Charles Bailey - No, you have to do `git show HEAD:file` to get contents of file. For index, `git show :a`. It is clearly specified in `gitrevisions`

Comment: @manojlds: Which part of the man pages mentions that `git show file` filters to `file`?

Answer (score 2):

`git show test.rb` can be rewritten as `git show -- test.rb`. This form makes it more obvious that you're calling `git show` and filtering the output to just `test.rb`. Since `git show` defaults to showing `HEAD`, this is the same as `git show HEAD -- test.rb`. Basically, it will show the commit info, but only give you a diff for the specific file `test.rb`.

However, `git show HEAD:test.rb` is explicitly instructing `git show` that the object you want to show is the blob that lives at the path `test.rb` reachable from the tree associated with the `HEAD` commit.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: True, if `test.rb` is the name of a branch or tag then it's ambiguous. But it's actually *not* the case here. Since `test.rb` isn't the name of a branch or tag, it's unambiguously the name of a file pattern, and that's used to filter the output of `git diff-tree` (which `git show` invokes).